# Retrieve CPU utilization for each Google Cloud App Engine instance

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I've deployed an app on Google Cloud App Engine instances.
I've enabled an autoscaling group that should increase the number of instances in case the CPU utilization of the instances goes beyond the 60% usage (as Google suggests).

Now from GCP dashboard I see these screen:
[image]

As you can see there are 3 instances (I've set the minimum number of instances to 3).

Hovering the blue line of the graph I see that CPU percentage changes over time, but I can't understand if this percentage is the total percentage for the 3 instances of what else.

In the image above 5.38% is the CPU percentage of a specific instance or is the sum of the percentage of the 3 instances?

I wonder to know how to retrieve CPU utilization for each of the 3 instances.

Comment: Event in CLoud Monitoring you have the CPU utilisation across all the instances. It should be not possible.  But why do you need the cpu usage per instance?

Comment: Have you checked the above comment?